# SwiftUI: matchedGeometryEffect not transitioning smoothly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list of countries. Each row has an image of a country as the background. I used to have it where clicking on a country row would navigate to a new view that displayed info on the country but I am testing out using the same view to accomplish this. I am setting the state of selectedCountry when tapping a country item and trying to use matchedGeometryEffect to make the image transition. Each country has hardcoded JSON data so the id field is a hardcoded ID coming from a JSON. I ensured the id and namespace match but I am still seeing a "flash" transition rather than a smooth one I would expect.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace;
    @Binding var countries: [Country(id: 0, display_name: "USA", image: "image_1"), Country(id: 1, display_name: "Canada", image: "image_2")]
    @State var selectedCountry: Country?;


    var body: some View {
        if (selectedCountry != nil) {
            VStack {
                Text("mainImage-\(self.selectedCountry!.id)")
                Image("\(selectedCountry!.image)-bg")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .overlay(Rectangle().opacity(0.2))
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "main\(self.selectedCountry!.id)", in: namespace)
                    .mask(
                        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black, Color.black.opacity(0)]), startPoint: .center, endPoint: .bottom)
                    )

                Spacer()
                Text("test close")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedCountry = nil
                    }
            }
        }
        if (selectedCountry ==  nil) {
            GeometryReader { bounds in
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(Array(filteredCountries.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,country) in
                        LazyVStack {
                            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                                Text("mainImage-\(country.id)")
                                Image("\(country.image)-bg")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                                    .overlay(Rectangle().opacity(0.2))
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "main\(country.id)", in: namespace)
                                    .mask(
                                        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black, Color.black.opacity(0)]), startPoint: .center, endPoint: .bottom)
                                    )
                            }
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation() {
                                self.selectedCountry = country;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding gif below to show the broken behavior:

[image]

Comment: It seems like you incorporated my suggestion from your last question to fix the `matchedGeometryEffect` id. Now this works for me. I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. Please add a small video or gif that displays what the issue is.

Comment: @burnsi yes, thank you -- I made the change you suggested but it still doesn't work for me.  I attached the gif above to my question to show how it appears in my simulator.  As you can see, it's a jarring change rather than the smooth transition